# How do I enable email notifications from Discord?

Tags: email, discord

My friend doesn't want to leave Discord running in the background when not in use. Instead, she would like to have Discord notifications sent to her email address.

I was able to find a help article explaining how to [disable email notifications](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001657287-How-can-I-stop-email-notifications-from-Discord-), but I haven't found a way to re-enable email notifications once they have been turned off.

**How can I enable email notifications from Discord?**

Comment: [I checked and there is currently no way to re-enable them. Sorry about that.](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/5qhu8n/how_do_i_reenable_notification_emails/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2021-09-17, it is now possible to get back email notifications:

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408820335767-How-can-I-manage-my-email-notifications-settings-

> Navigate to your User Settings by pressing the Cog button at the bottom left of the app:
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> Select ‘Notifications’ on the left menu and then scroll down until you see ‘Email Notifications’. From here, you can see more information about each type of notification and select just the ones you want.
>
> If you would like to unsubscribe from all notifications, you can uncheck each notification type or simply click ‘Unsubscribe from all marketing emails’ at the bottom of the Email Notifications section:
>
> [image: screenshot]

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with getting email notifications about DMs or mentions or whatever in Discord. It has to do with emails they might send out for other reasons. This should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @rfay Well the first item in the list is "Receive emails for missed calls, messages, and message digests". Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I've had that set forever, have never had an email notification.

Answer (score 10):

I did further research and discovered that as of this date there is no way to re-enable email notifications if you have opted to disable them previously. It is assumed they are on by default prior to opting out.

Referecne:

1. https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360030123192-Re-enable-email-notifications
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/5qhu8n/how_do_i_reenable_notification_emails/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I specifically emailed them about this recently.  Discord support said to upvote the thread if you want this request.   Why is such a basic feature needing a vote?

Comment: Not relevant anymore, it is now possible to [manage email notifications](https://superuser.com/a/1694865/88801).